# PHP time script

Tags: php, arrays, datetime

I have the following function

```
function status($open, $lunch, $close)
{
 if(date('H') < $open || date('H') > $close)
 {
  $GLOBALS['status'] = "Closed";
  $GLOBALS['color'] = "rgba(255,0,0,1)";
 }
 elseif(date('H') == ($close-1))
 {
  if(date('i') > 29)
  {
   $GLOBALS['status'] = "Closing";
   $GLOBALS['color'] = "rgba(255,255,0,1)";
  }
  else
  {
   $GLOBALS['status'] = "Open";
   $GLOBALS['color'] = "rgba(0,255,0,1)";
  }
 }
 else
 {
  if(date('H') == $lunch)
  {
   $GLOBALS['status'] = "Lunch";
   $GLOBALS['color'] = "rgba(0,0,255,1)";
  }
  else
  {
   $GLOBALS['status'] = "Open";
   $GLOBALS['color'] = "green";
  }
 }
}
```

and after 10:00PM it is supposed to return the status of closed and right now its 10:13 and it's still returning open, I've gone through the code and cannot seem to find the problem.

Could someone take a look and see where my code is failing??

Comment: `10:00`PM, you inputted `22` on closing?

Comment: when I call the function it is written status(10,12,22). but for some reason it is registering the final else statement.

Comment: what is the time zone your php server is in? Might need to make adjustment to time zone or daylight savings time.

Comment: @GaryHayes The timezone is correct and when I have the server return the time it returns the time I am expecting

Comment: Looking like a problem with your nested if else statements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `>=` on closing.

```
if(date('H') < $open || date('H') >= $close)
{
    $GLOBALS['status'] = "Closed";
    $GLOBALS['color'] = "rgba(255,0,0,1)";
}
```

What happened is you set `10:00 PM` which is `22`. If the current time is `10:13` which is still not greater than `22`. That's why it did fail the condition. Should be greater than or equal, then, it's closed.

Comment: when I originally wrote the script I had put the equals sign in, but when I edited it this afternoon, I must have removed it. Thank you for pointing out my mistake

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
function status($open, $lunch, $close)
{
    $hour = date('H');
    $minute = date('i');

    if($hour < $open ||  $hour >= $close)
    {
        $GLOBALS['status'] = "Closed";
        $GLOBALS['color'] = "rgba(255,0,0,1)";
    }
    else if($hour==$lunch)
    {
        $GLOBALS['status'] = "Lunch";
        $GLOBALS['color'] = "rgba(0,0,255,1)";
    }
    else
    {
        $GLOBALS['status'] = "Open";
        $GLOBALS['color'] = "green";
    }

    if($hour == ($close-1) && $minute>29)
    {
        $GLOBALS['status'] = "Closing";
        $GLOBALS['color'] = "rgba(255,255,0,1)";
    }
}
```

**NOTE :** also set your default timezone like

```
date_default_timezone_set('your timezone');
//example
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the correct time zone set,

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Colombo');
```

List of timezones supported in php can be found [here](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php)

Comment: timezone is set to America/Vancouver in my .user.ini file on the server